# Configure voice interface and phone on a cisco router

Tags: telephony, cisco

In order to understand how does telephony works with a router a have the following configuration :

- 2 phones (Bosch TM13)
- 1 router (cisco 3600)
- 1 voice cards on the router (the card is VIC-2FXS)
- Each phone is connected to the voice card with RJ11 cables

[image: Here is the scheme of the configuration]

I made a simple configuration on the router (following the advices of cisco website), which is exactly what you can see on the picture above. I do not have configured any voice-port but they are up and running and according to several website the default configuration is sufficient.

The problem is that I can't make a phone call...

I have several questions:

- Is it normal not to hear dial tone when the phone is in off-hook state ?
- Does I need to configure voice-port ?

Comment: You will be better off taking this question to a different StackExchange site, SO is mostly programming... I would suggest ServerFault.

Comment: ok I'll do that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bosch TM13" are used for ISDN networks so it cannot work with this configuration.